# Imageresizer.net flickr size

Tags: imageresizer

With Flickr you can query for images with a size parameter instead of specifying the exact dimensions. I've had a look and I can't see the same way in ImageResizer to do the same

I've started to write a custom Plugin that will detect the "size" query string and perform a lookup in a config file / database / hardcoded to get the size of the image required, then handing that back to the standard ImageResizer functionality to continue.

What I have so far is a class that implements ImageBuilder, IPlugin, IQuerystringPlugin and overrides the GetSupportedQuerystringKeys() method to return new string[] { "size" }

I've also overridden the GetFinalSize() method of the ImageBuilder class but this is never getting hit when running in debug mode. I'm making a request to the url /myimage.jpg?size=small.

Is this the correct approach to take for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are translating one querystring command into another set of querystring commands, then you should handle the `Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite` event. You can subscribe/unsubscribe to the event within your plugin during install/uninstall. You should *not* need to inherit from ImageBuilder or override *GetFinalSize*.  IPlugin and IQuerystringPlugin should be sufficient.